# How to create a method that calls a bunch of methods asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have the following method:

```
private async void CreateSchedule(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
   using (var db = new SolverDbContext())
   {
      foreach (var date in dates)
      {
         var job = await client.ConfigureJob(new JobConfigurationModel
         {
            ScheduleDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            // Bunch of other stuff that doesn't matter
         });

         var dbSchedule = Schedule.Default;
         dbSchedule.Ticket = job;
         dbSchedule.ScheduleDate = date;
         db.Schedule.Add(dbSchedule);
      }

      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Basically it loops through a bunch of dates and calls an awaitable method called `ConfigureJob` (Which makes an HTTP call to a web service).

Now, I want to call this method.  I've tried:

```
CreateSchedule(allDates);
```

This will just no-op and exit immediately.  I've also tried:

```
Task.Run(() => { CreateSchedule(allDates); }).Wait();
```

This does the same.

It seems I have to make `CreateSchedule` return a `Task<T>` or enumeration of Tasks to wait on.  What's the correct approach here?

Comment: Don't use async void, they are intended for event handlers. Return a Task and await it all the way up.

Comment: You should not use `async void` instead use `async Task`. You should also be `await`ing the call to that function to make it asynchronous.

Comment: Ah perfect!  I didn't realize methods will just implicitly return a Task if there's no `return` statement in the asynchronous method.  Also, @RonBeyer - I can't `await` the call to `CreateSchedule` because this is called within a Unit Test, and Unit Tests don't support `async`.  However, I can just `.Wait()` on the `CreateSchedule()` call.  One of you, feel free to write an answer and I'll upvote/accept.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Which version of Visual Studio are you using? `async`/`await` unit test support was added in VS2012. Many testing frameworks support async tests.

Comment: @RonBeyer - VS2013.  When I try marking the test as async and run the test, it just says "Failed" (No error code, exception thrown, anything in Output, etc).  One thing to note, I call this async method in a `[TestInitialize]` method, not a `[TestMethod]` - Not sure if that makes a difference..

Comment: @MikeChristensen In that case, just do `CreateSchedule(allDates).Wait()` and change `CreateSchedule` to be `async Task` instead of `void`.

Comment: @RonBeyer - Yup that's what I did.  Do test initialization methods not support async then?

Comment: That I'm not sure of, but it seems no, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375130/mstest-async-testinitialize-guarantee-test-fail

Comment: @RonBeyer - Yea ran across [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a23bd9d-7a5a-490e-a199-b8dfa309f39e/unittesting-problem-with-async-testinitialize-method?forum=vstest) as well.  It states [TestMethod] supports async, but not [TestInitialize].  Probably makes sense, as you have to block until your test is initialized anyway, so there's not really a point to make it async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `async void`, that is intended for use as in event handlers. Instead you should be returning a Task.

```
private async Task CreateSchedule(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
   // The rest of your code can remain the same.
}
```

Then in your consuming code, you should use async semantics all the way up, so you should await that result in a method that returns a `Task`:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestScheduler()
{
    // .. Maybe some prep work here ..
    await CreateSchedule(allDates);
    // .. Do Some Assert Checks Here ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll also point out that I'm calling `CreateSchedule` from within a `[TestInitialize]` method, which doesn't support `async`.  Instead, I have to use: `CreateSchedule(allDates).Wait();`

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know what async/await do that a regular blocking method call doesn't? Everybody knows how to use them, but I can't find anything about what they do. The example code I've found just blocks like any ordinary method call.

Comment: @EdPlunkett It does not block, it returns to the calling function at the point of the `await` with a `Task` that represents the rest of the function. The unit test code has special stuff to not mark the test complete until the returned task completes without errors.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - It's basically compiler trickery to save you from having to write all sorts of delegates for asynchronous programming.  You just write things the way they logically make sense.  But as Scott said, `await` will *not* block the thread; the method exits immediately and the rest of the method is wrapped up into a delegate which is called later.

Comment: @MikeChristensen That's what I've read that it does. My own error then, I guess; I was trying to use it to asynchronously call a web service without blocking the UI thread. Couldn't make it do that. Not a big deal, I can write threads fine without it.